# What database technologies should I consider for building a scalable "running average" view?

Tags: sql-server

We are working on an application where millions of users will be entering information at the same time.  Suppose the application allows people to rate geographic regions on where they would like to live.  Each participant is allowed to rate each region using a decimal value from 0-10.  Each person belongs to one or more groups based upon attributes such as gender, and people that consider themselves active, or enjoy culture.

Every time a rating is made, we need to have a view which shows us the average rating for each region/group.  I'm aware that most DB's have an "average" function, but for our purposes we need to be able to use our own function as we may use a the geometric mean instead of the arithmetic mean.

Below are some tables which might be used. **Note:** I did not include the relationship table **PeopleGroups** which map which groups a person is a member of for brevity purposes.

```
Regions               People            Groups              RegionScoresByPerson
+-----+------------+  +-----+-------+   +-----+----------+  +-----+-----+-------+
| RID |    NAME    |  | PID | Name  |   | GID |   Name   |  | RID | PID | Score |
+-----+------------+  +-----+-------+   +-----+----------+  +-----+-----+-------+
|   1 | Flordia    |  | P1  | Alice |   | G0  | Everyone |  |   1 | P1  |     6 |
|   2 | California |  | P2  | Bob   |   | G1  | Women    |  |   1 | P2  |     8 |
+-----+------------+  | P3  | Frank |   | G2  | Men      |  |   1 | P3  |     3 |
                      | P4  | Mary  |   | G3  | Active   |  |   1 | P4  |     2 |
                      +-----+-------+   | G4  | Culture  |  |   1 | P1  |     7 |
                                        +-----+----------+  |   1 | P2  |     5 |
                                                            |   1 | P3  |     8 | 
                                                            |   1 | P4  |     2 | 
                                                            +-----+-----+-------+
```

Our current implementation uses a similar set of tables for storing ratings, but we don't calculate averages real-time.  Anytime we need the results (e.g. show me the average score California for women), we have to pull all the information into memory and run the calculations manually.

I was wondering how I leverage database technologies such as views, triggers, stored procedures, etc. to present to me a simple table that will allow me to get scores by for people and groups so we don't have to manually run calculations.

I would like some table like the following, where everything is handled by the DB.  Any insert,update,delete actions on the **RegionScoresByPerson** or **Groups** tables would automatically be reflected in this table.  If it is not apparent, the rows marked with * calculated rows.  In this case I'm using a simple arithmetic average, but I the design should allow for any type of function.

**EID** stands for entity ID (a person or group)

Besides deciding how to build such a view, I'm unsure of what sort of datatypes to use (and index) for **People** and **Groups**.  I suppose I'd like the index to be integers, but that would prevent me from creating the table below because I couldn't distinguish between Person 1 and Group 1 -- Would having ID's such as P1 and G1 be a performance hit? I'm obviously concerned about the design being scalable.

```
ScoreView
+-----------+-----+-------+
| RID       | EID | Score |
| 1         | P1  | 6     |
| 1         | P2  | 8     |
| 1         | P3  | 3     |
| 1         | P4  | 2     |
| 1         | P1  | 7     |
| 1         | P2  | 5     |
| 1         | P3  | 8     |
| 1         | P4  | 2     |
| 1         | G0  | 4.75  |*
| 1         | G1  | 4     |*
| 1         | G2  | …     |*
| 1         | G3  | …     |*
+-----------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: It can be expensive to update the rating table using a trigger in real time, if you have to deal with millions of users. You don't want to calculate the ratings using views either because every query has to calculate them.  You can do an every-minute update, with shorter or longer interval.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Flume is the open source tool designed to solve this kind of problem. Also have a look at Google Cloud Dataflow.

https://flume.apache.org/